# How do I use the hidden column in mtcars dataset to label scatterplot in R?

Tags: r

I have plotted a scatterplot using the mtcars dataset in R with mpg on the x-axis and wt on the y-axis. I am now trying to label the data points based on the first column (the model of the car), but since this column doesn't have any name, I am not able to label the plot

```
attach(mtcars)
plot(mpg,wt,
     xlab = "Miles per Gallon",
     ylab = "Weight of car (in metric tonnes)",
     col = "blue" , pch = 19)    

text(mpg,wt, labels = "?" , cex = 0.7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `rownames(mtcars)`.

```
fo <- wt ~ mpg
plot(fo, mtcars,
     xlab = "Miles per Gallon",
     ylab = "Weight of car (in metric tonnes)",
     col = "blue" , pch = 19)    

text(fo, mtcars, labels = rownames(mtcars) , cex = 0.7)
```

[image: screenshot]